# Wikidata Query list of languages spoken in a city

Tags: javascript, sparql, mediawiki-api, wikidata

Can't seem to figure this out 
I want to generate a list from wiki data that shows all the languages found in a city

E.G  South African languages and their locations

```
Country          Language           Province
South Africa --- Afrikaans -------- KwaZulu-Natal
South Africa --- Afrikaans -------- Cape Town
South Africa --- Northern Sotho ---- Free State
South Africa --- Swazi --------------Durban
South Africa --- Tsonga ------------- Lesotho
```

I also don't want to limit the results to Official languages
as many countries have several languages that are not officially recognized.
as show here.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Languages_of_South_Africa

this is what I currently have

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?lang ?langLabel ?Country ?CountryLabel ?City ?CityLabel
WHERE
{
    ?lang  wdt:P31 wd:Q34770 .
    ?Country wdt:P31 wd:Q6256 . 
    VALUES ?Country {wd:Q258 }  

 VALUES ?Country {wd:Q258 }  

 SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }

}

LIMIT 100
```

I'm currently using the Javascript wikidata-sdk

Comment: and you're not able to get the cities of a country? I don't think that languages are attached to cities, at least I can't find such an information for [Pretoria](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q3926)

Comment: I’m open to ideas on a work around even if it involves using another api

Comment: Could https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P2936 be added to city items? Although I guess it'd be applied to the largest geographical entity (maybe that's the city, but maybe it's the region/state/etc.).